# How to track user current location even app is terminated in flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation

I make a app which continuously track the current location from user side even if app is terminated and show in admin side, like I can track the order on zomato and show in map.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin bro flutter_background_geolocation
[flutter_background_geolocation](https://%20https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation)

Comment: is there any other way? because it's paid package